# TextArea suggest the previously entered values

Tags: html

I want the textarea to suggest the previously entered values, something similar to what we have for textbox.
Is there a way it can be done using any html property or js. I don't want to store the previous values in any array or local storage, everything must be maintained by the browser.

Comment: Well for that you either use *Chosen* or *Select2*.

Comment: using a cookie?

Comment: `I don't want to store the previous values in any array or local storage, everything must be maintained by the browser.`

Did you know that local storage is maintained by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

The reload is done on change event, which is triggered after 500ms or when the  loses focus.
Setting the focus before the value ensures the prompt stays at the end.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var time;
    if($.cookie('fioFilter')!=null)
 {
  $("#fioFilter").focus().text($.cookie('fioFilter'));
 }
 $("#fioFilter").keyup(function(e){
        clearTimeout(time);
  $.cookie("fioFilter",$("#fioFilter").val());
        time=setTimeout(function(){$("#fioFilter").change();},500);
 });
 $("#fioFilter").change(function(e){
  window.location.reload();
 });
});
```

```html
<!--Adding jquery cookie library-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<textarea id='fioFilter' class='filter'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a javascript based library. You can't do autocomplete on textarea . The autocomplete attribute works with the following `<input>` types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color.

A number of plugins can do this task on textarea:

[Textcomplete](https://yuku-t.com/textcomplete/) || [At.js](http://ichord.github.io/At.js/) || [Bootstrap-Tag-Autocomplete](https://sandglaz.github.io/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/)